# Python: How to apply WEB palette after Image.fromarray() using Pillow?

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, color-palette

Pillow can convert bytes array to image:

```
img = Image.fromarray((data).astype('uint8'), 'P')
```

but it will be a grayscale image.
I know that PIL has an `img.putpalette(some_palette)` method

How can I get WEB palette to apply it for the image?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by WEB palette but
Palette in pillow is defined by an array contains a sequence of rgb values.
ex

```
im.putpalette([
  0, 0, 0, # black background
  255, 0, 0, # index 1 is red
  255, 255, 0, # index 2 is yellow
  255, 153, 0, # index 3 is orange
])
```

So you may want to lookup the rgb values for your palette, and do this in your code.

```
im = Image.fromarray((data).astype('uint8'), 'P')
im.putpalette(some_palette)
```

[reference](http://effbot.org/zone/creating-palette-images.htm)